# Ubuntu 22.04 wont start

Tags: boot, bios

I have a problem with Ubuntu. I install it with legacy or UEFI. For some reason after 2-3 days BIOS losing 3 hours, and Ubuntu won't boot at all.
By the time I install the OS, everything is starting and working OK.

In Linux 5.19.0-32 I can start the system. In Linux 5.19.0-46 the system won't boot. Black screen.

Please some Help.
I'm new to Ubuntu
Thanks Loukas

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].